# How can I add two functions together in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

For example I have two functions expressed with two lists:

```
x_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_1 = [2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2]

x_2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y_2 = [2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2]
```

and the result should be

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [2, 4, 3, 9, 2, 7, 1, 2]
```

Here I set the x values in the integer lattice but it is not necessary. But I guess one solution could be normalizing them onto the lattice and then add them.

Is there any simple method to do this? Numpy and Scipy are both available.

Thanks!

---

A simple illustration
[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you got the o/p?

Comment: @BhargavRao Sorry but what is o/p?

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks. The y values corresponding to the same x sums up.

Comment: So you want to merge 2 (pairs) of lists, based on the values of one.  What assumptions are you making about the `x` values?  Do they overlap, are they contiguous?

Comment: @hpaulj There's no restriction on x. You can imagine two functions, both described by x,y values and every function is connected by a straight line between two defined x values next to each other.

Comment: Are you happy with the solution that treats this as set union?

Comment: @hpaulj As said in the comment, that solution is not fast and did not consider the condition that the x values are not on the lattice, so there's space to improve.

Comment: In the range where `x` values overlap, are they guaranteed to match?  Even if float values?  You may think of these as functions, but in the code they will just be lists or arrays of numbers (integer or float).  Give us some code that works for all cases, even if it is iterative.  Worry about speed later.

Comment: @hpaulj They are not guaranteed to match and could be float values. I think the solution could be get a latticed function using interpolation then add them up. But it is to be slow if I do this with pure python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` has a 1d interpolation function, and `scipy` has a more general one(s).

A simple approach with `np.interp`:

```
x1,y1=[0,1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,1,5,1,2]
x2,y2=[2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,4,1,5,1,2]
x3 = np.arange(x1[0],x2[-1]+1)  # or latice of your choice
np.interp(x3,x1,y1,0,0) + np.interp(x3,x2,y2,0,0)
```

producing:

```
array([ 2.,  4.,  3.,  9.,  2.,  7.,  1.,  2.])
```

I told `interp` to return 0 for values outside the `x1` range, which seems to fit your addition scheme well.

A couple of other ways of constructing `x3`:

Join the 2 lists, and ask for the unique values (sorted):

```
x3=np.unique(x1+x2)
```

or if the `x` might already be arrays, concatenate them first:

```
x3=np.unique(np.concatenate([x1,x2]))
```

Comment: I think that's what I want! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Naive implementation:

```
x_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_1 = [2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2]

x_2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y_2 = [2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2]

f1 = dict(zip(x_1, y_1))
f2 = dict(zip(x_2, y_2))

x = list(set(f1.keys()) | set(f2.keys()))
y = [f1.get(k, 0) + f2.get(k, 0) for k in x]

print x
print y
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[2, 4, 3, 9, 2, 7, 1, 2]
```

Comment: `set(f1.keys() + f2.keys())` does not work in Python 3.x because `dict.keys` returns a view object, not a list object in Python 3.x. Use `set(list(f1) + list(f2))` or `set(f1) | set(f2)`, ...

Comment: Thank you a lot! How about the situation where the x values are not on the lattice? Besides, since I have to deal with huge functions, maybe numpy will be better in performance?